# Thread, Asynctask or intentService for my app?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask, bluetooth

I need your opinion for my app. I'm developing an app which communicates with a radio via bluetooth. App is divided into 3 (swipe) **tabs** :

1. In the first I put a connection option and a "**connect**" button to connect my device to a radio.
2. In the second there is a map which shows my position (radio can send a GPS string, I decode it with my algorithm and I obtain latitude and longitude).
3. In the third there is a similar bluetooth chat option with which I can send/receive simple text message to the radio.

This app must stay in **background** and connected to the radio and it must show (similar to an SMS) in the notification area an icon which says "message received". So I want your opinion to develop the app: I have to use a *thread/asynctask* for connection, a *thread/asynctask* for the map and a intentservice for the messages or what do you think should be done? This is my first app in background, last month I implemented a part of my app with asynctask.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: They have a bluetooth chat sample in the sdk, you could base your app on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` should be used when you have to perform a short-lived operation on a separate thread and post the final result on the main / UI thread, which is not the case with your app I believe.

`Service` should be used to perform long-running tasks which take place in the background and continue working irrespective of whether there is an `Activity` in the foreground or not. `Service`, though, still runs on the main thread, which means that if you do a lot of heavy computations on this `Service`, it will slow down your UI (when the UI is present).

Which brings us to `IntentService`, which performs a long-running operation *on a separate thread* **and** works in the background irrespective of whether an `Activity` is present or not.

So `IntentService` is probably the best bet in a situation where you want a smooth UI but you also have work going on in the background independent of the UI components of the app (`AsyncTask` cannot do this). However, your work is cut out for you, as you will still have to synchronize / bind the `IntentService` with the `Activity` when you want to transmit data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is a thing i don't understand: Must I create three intentservice (one for connection, one for map and one for message) or only one for the three tabs?

Comment: This really depends on how many things you want to do, and how you want to notify the user of the data gathered and functions performed. If you can do all your work in one `IntentService`, then send the complete data to the `Activity` and then split the data into three pieces, one for each tab, then that would be the best. The reason is, the more the number of `IntentService`s, the harder the synchronization with the `Activity`, and also the greater the memory/CPU resources required by your app. So you need to think about this carefully ... split up your work into parts and try to minimize.

Comment: So if I use one intentservice I use less memory?

Comment: Yes, definitely ... and also less coding for you :) see also [this article i found](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/).

Comment: I don't understand one thing: how can I call the same IntentService from three classes? I don't know how to manage introduction, map and message..

Comment: You will have a single `Activity` that holds the three tabs, right ? So your `IntentService` has to communicate with just this one `Activity` :)

Comment: And how can I communicate with the three fragments?

Comment: Once the data is in the `Activity`, it can easily be shared with the `Fragment`s ... do a little research and you will learn how :)

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how to pass from activity to intentservice, and how I can divide intentservice into 3 parts...

Comment: There are ways for an `IntentService` to communicate with an `Activity`, just do a little research on that ... and if you feel it would be easier for you to use 3 `IntentService`s, then you can do that :)

Comment: You give me a hand very well :) so i don't understand how to call the service for the activity..could I call the service near the addTab call or in which place? Because I don't understand this..if it's possible I could pass you a part of my activity code...

Comment: Sorry, it's possible to use two IntentService, one for connection and one for message, and one asynctask for the map?